# How to use video DOM method load() in jQuery context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to use https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp

```
$('.activ').mouseover(function(){
   $("#videologo2").load();
});
```

And I get `jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated`

Also, this vanilla JS works:

```
$('.activ').mouseover(function(){
   document.getElementById("videologo2").load();
});
```

This is the HTML context

```
<div id="solapa" class="close">
  <div class="logo">
    <video id="videologo2" autoplay loop muted>
      <source class="webm_src" src="ruido.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source class="ogg_src" src="ruido.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the right way? Thanks!

The entire script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.activ').mouseover(function(){
        $(".webm_src").src = mrg_var.templateDirectoryUri+"/dist/images/video/actividades.webmsd.webm";
        $(".ogg_src").src = mrg_var.templateDirectoryUri+"/dist/images/video/actividades.oggtheora.ogv";
        $("#videologo2").load();
    });
});
```

This is the snipet with the solution.

```js
$('#button-1-js').click(function(){
console.log('button-1-js');
            document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/actividades.mp4.mp4";
            document.getElementById("webm_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/actividades.webmsd.webm";
            document.getElementById("ogg_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.orgapp/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/actividades.oggtheora.ogv";
            // document.getElementById("videologo").load();
            $("#videologo").get(0).load();
});

$('#button-2-js').click(function(){
console.log('button-2-js');
            document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/convoca.mp4.mp4";
            document.getElementById("webm_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/convoca.webmsd.webm";
            document.getElementById("ogg_src").src = "http://stage.margenesdelarte.orgapp/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/convoca.oggtheora.ogv";
            // document.getElementById("videologo").load();
            $("#videologo").get(0).load();
});
```

```css
video {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="videologo" autoplay loop muted>
      <source id="mp4_src" src="http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/ruido.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source id="webm_src" src="http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/ruido.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source id="ogg_src" src="http://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/video/ruido.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>

<button id="button-1-js" type="button">Video 1</button>
<button id="button-2-js" type="button">Video 2</button>
```

Comment: Your plain JS example should have worked fine as it's calling the correct method (as opposed to your jQuery which is attempting to trigger a `load` event on the video). Can you explain more about what you want this code to do. Note that simply calling `load()` will not have any effect on the UI. You may need to call `play()` afterwards, if that's what you want to happen

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm trying to change video source on mouseover of an element. I've omitted the new sources for simplicity, but I'll go to edit the question to include all script.

Comment: Just FYI, @RoryMcCrossan You was right.  Plain JS was working. Video not change but it is because another problem, maybe related to file path.

Answer (score 1):

try using this code,

```
$('.activ').mouseover(function(){
  $("#videologo2").get(0).load();
});
```

Comment: Tryed it, unsuccesfully. Nothing happens when I run $("#videologo2").on("load")

Comment: actually..faster solution for now you can using javascript rather than jquery..document.getElementById("videologo2").load(); and $(".webm_src").attr('src','movie.mp4');

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. I marked your anwer as solution although it lacks of an explanation (see new snipet attached to question).